# Jquery Datatables style not working in asp net core razor pages partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datatables, razor-pages

I have a partial view that has a datatable to show list of customers. Everything works fine except that datatables is not styled and search is not shown. I have added all the references and tried it on [This JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jobiraw/tpo53mf4/6/) and it works fine. But when it comes to my razor pages it doesn't.I have included  screenshot of my out pit at the end.Below is my code.

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body class="sb-nav-fixed">
        @RenderBody()
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>   
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Custormers.cshtml**

```
@model Web.Pages.Customer.CustomersModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Registration";
}
<div class="card">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding:20px">
        <a onclick="jQueryModalGet('?handler=CreateOrEdit','New Customer')" class="btn btn-success">
            Create
        </a>
        
        <a id="reload" class="btn bg-warning">
            Reload
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="viewAll" class="card-body table-responsive"></div>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#viewAll').load('?handler=ViewAllPartial');
        });
        $(function () {
            $('#reload').on('click', function () {
                $('#viewAll').load('?handler=ViewAllPartial');
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

**CustomersModel.cs**

```
{
    public class CustomersModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ICustomerRepository _customer;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private readonly IRazorRenderService _renderService;
        private readonly ILogger<CustomersModel> _logger;

        public CustomersModel(ILogger<CustomersModel> logger, ICustomerRepository customer, IRazorRenderService renderService)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _customer = customer;
            _renderService = renderService;
        }
        public IEnumerable<Core.Entities.Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<CustomerModel> CustomerModel{ get; set; }
        
        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        public PartialViewResult OnGetViewAllPartial()
        {
            CustomerModel = _customer.GetAsync();
            return new PartialViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "_ViewAll",
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<IEnumerable<CustomerModel>>(ViewData, CustomerModel)
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**_ViewAll.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<CustomerModel>


<table class="display" id="#dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                FirstName
            </th>
            <th>
                LastName
            </th>
            <th>
                Age
            </th>
            <th>
                PhoneNumber
            </th>
            <th>
                Address
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Model.Count() != 0)
        {
            @foreach (var customer in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @customer.FirstName
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @customer.LastName
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @customer.Age
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @customer.PhoneNumber
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @customer.Address
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dataTable").DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

**Update** Network tab of the Bwroser
[image: CSS loaded fine]
[image: jQuery Loaded fine]
[image: Datatables loaded fine]
[image: Output Image]

Comment: Do you have any errors in Console of browser?And is the css file loaded correctly in NetWork?

Comment: No there are no errors in the console. Also the css is loaded in network...could it be because I am looping to feed the data to the datatable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,you need to change `id="#dataTable"` to `id="dataTable"`.And then put `dataTables.min.css`,`dataTables.min.js` and js code into Custormers.cshtml.

_ViewAll.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<CustomerModel>


<table class="display" id="dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                FirstName
            </th>
            <th>
                LastName
            </th>
            <th>
                Age
            </th>
            <th>
                PhoneNumber
            </th>
            <th>
                Address
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Model.Count() != 0)
        {
            @foreach (var customer in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @customer.FirstName
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @customer.LastName
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @customer.Age
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @customer.PhoneNumber
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @customer.Address
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Custormers.cshtml:

```
@model Web.Pages.Customer.CustomersModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Registration";
}
<div class="card">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding:20px">
        <a onclick="jQueryModalGet('?handler=CreateOrEdit','New Customer')" class="btn btn-success">
            Create
        </a>
        
        <a id="reload" class="btn bg-warning">
            Reload
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="viewAll" class="card-body table-responsive"></div>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#viewAll').load('?handler=ViewAllPartial', function () {
                $("#dataTable").DataTable();
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

result:
[image]

Comment: thank you so much...now i am laughing on my self

Comment: also all the css and js files are still in the layout and it works

Answer (score 0):

If the style is missing the the CSS is not loading correctly, as well for the datatable.js file is the search bar is missing. Please inspect your code and send a capture, check for any error on inspector console and share the feedback.

Comment: I have added screenshot of the network tab please check it nothing is missing

Comment: Your response is not an answer. This is quite like a comment for the post. It seems you are sending this as a response due to the lack of privilege to post comments. Since you got that access, you need to submit only the answers.

Comment: Ok got it, thanks for the warning, I'll wait to have the right permissions. ;-)